Diophantine taxi numbers : $n = p q r = a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 $ for primes $p,q,r$ (example $1729$)
There is something special about $1729$.
$$1729 = 10^3 + 9^3 = 12^3 + 1^3$$
It is the sum of two positive integer cubes in exactly two ways.
(In fact it is the smallest such integer, but that is not so important here)
We also know by Fermat little that $10 + 9 = 19$ and $12 + 1 = 13$ must be divisors of $1729$.
Since $19$ and $13$ share no common divisor we can divide $1729$ by their product.
Also $19$ and $13$ are prime, so we have two prime factors.
$$1729 = 19 * 13 * 7 $$
The $7$ follows easily from division by $19$ and $13$.
So we conclude that $1729$ is the product of $3$ primes.
So we found a positive integer $n$
such that
$$ n = p q r $$
for primes $p,q,r$
and
$$ n = a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 $$
for positive integers $a,b,c,d$.
From fermats last theorem or a weaker version we know $p,q,r$ cannot be all the same numbers since
the diophantine
$$ A^3 + B^3 = C^3 $$
has no solution for $ABC > 0$.
So at least $2$ of $p,q,r$ must be distinct.
This also implies that $n$ is cubefree, which limits the number of solutions we can build from a given one.
Since $n$ is cubefree, $a,b$ have no common divisor and neither do $c,d$.
So one wonders if there are more positive integer $n$ such that :
$$ n = p q r $$
for primes $p,q,r$
and
$$ n = a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 $$
for positive integers $a,b,c$.
In fact, I conjecture there are infinitely many such $n$.
It may be naive, but it seems there is no reason the density of such numbers can be estimated by assuming the probability $A$ that an integer is the sum of 2 cubes in 2 ways and the probability $B$ that a number is a product of 3 primes, are independant probabilities.
Thereby giving the total probability $AB$.
Then again we noticed that $a + b = p$, $c + d = q$, so the independance might be a bit missing the connection.
Proving the density by a good estimate might be a bit much to expect, but can we at least prove there are infinitely many such $n$ ?
Is there a sieving method that gives a proof ?

Simpler thanFermat's little:$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.

See also https://oeis.org/A001235

@martycohen I was aware.

Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers, v.2, p.550 has a section on "Two EQUAL SuMs OF Two CUBES." However,  I wasn't able to make use of this to answer this question.

Note that the three primes, and all the primes in VTand's answer, are primes of the form $6n+1$.  That isn't an accident.  The relevance to sums of cubes is via the following: 1) Euler's $6n+1$ theorem: every prime of that form can be expressed in the form $x^2+3y^2$; 2) the identity $a^3+b^3= x(x^2+3y^2)/4$ where $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$.

As listed in https://oeis.org/A272935, there are indeed other values of $n$. For example,
\begin{array}{rcccccl}
20683 &=& 10^3 + 27^3 &=& 19^3 + 24^3 &=& 37 \cdot 43 \cdot 13, \\
149389 &=& 8^3 + 53^3 &=& 29^3 + 50^3 &=& 61 \cdot 79 \cdot 31, \\
195841 &=& 9^3 + 58^3 &=& 22^3 + 57^3 &=& 67 \cdot 79 \cdot 37.\\
\end{array}
The OEIS page gives a link to a list of 131 solutions. I am unable to find a proof of whether there are infinitely many values of $n$ or not.
